# Are struct and ValueType equivalent

Tags: c#, generics

When defining generic type constraint, are those two equivalent:

```
public void Method<T>(T parameter) where T : struct { }
```

and

```
public void Method<T>(T parameter) where T : ValueType { }
```

From [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netcore-3.1), I strongly suspect that they are the same:

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, you cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly. Instead, individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support the creation of value types.

But I want to ensure that.

Comment: why not try out what the compiler does?

Comment: `ValueType` is one of those special classes where you'll find that the runtime doesn't have to abide by the same rules as the C# compiler enforces.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Because it won't compile :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in this case the runtime *does* enforce the same constraints, though; if you bypass the compiler and invoke such a method with reflection using `MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ValueType))` or `MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int?))`: you'll get an exception at runtime about how it "violates the constraint of type 'T'.". I can check with IL, but I *suspect* the JIT will shout too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not the same, because the second one *doesn't compile*:

> error CS0702: Constraint cannot be special class 'ValueType'

However, yes: `T : struct` means "T is a value type". The subtle distinction is that in theory `Method<ValueType>()` itself would satisfy `T : ValueType`, and `ValueType` *is a `class`*, not a `struct`.

Additionally, `T : struct` does not allow you to use *nullable `T?`*, i.e. `Method<int?>` is not legal, even though `int?` (aka `Nullable<int>`) is a value-type.

Comment: Wow, it just came to my mind and din't try it in code. Anyway, the way I put it perfectly states what I meant and with your answer clears hings up on how to constraint generic type to `ValueType` :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn note also the caveat I edited in at the end

Comment: So can I see `T : ValueType` as `T : struct` ?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes, as long as nobody actually ever expected to use `Method<ValueType>()` or `Method<int?>()`